# Connecting a trs wire to trrs jack

Tags: audio

[image]Hi, I have a headphone(trs) and its audio jack got broken and I have other earphones and I am wondering if I can connect the trs wire to trrs jack. please Inform me . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

￼yes you may use TRS wire. If you can connect it properly.[image]
￼[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only have three wires as pictured you can figure out which side is left and right by connecting an audio source to it and listening to the headphones.

Headphones should be wired with one common connector (ground) and one for left and right. As the drivers don't care about polarity so much you can connect the source either way around.

When you connect the source to left and right without a connection to ground, there will be no sound which will tell you which wire is ground. From this you can figure out left and right.

If you need an audio source you can use any audio device and just strip another mono cable so that you have a two wire output. If you choose a stereo cable again you may end up in the same situation of figuring out which wire is which!

Comment: Why don't they care about polarity?
I'm not an expert on this in any way so that's just a genuine question out of curiosity, I'm not questioning its validity.
I had speakers with a very special connector and I wanted to extend their wires and convert the connector into something that can actually be connected to devices. To test which one of the speaker wires were right vs left, I touched each pole of a battery with the wires. If the speaker membrane got sucked in, the polarity was wrong, and if the membrane bulged out, the polarity was correct. At least in speakers, wrong polarity can >

Comment: actually put the audio out of phase so when there's supposed to be audio, you get silence instead. Any sound technician who makes the audio mix be it speech or music or whatever, trusts that the final mix is listened through an audio system where the polarity is correct, so they can't take responsibility for how things will sound if your system is wired incorrectly. The difference most of the time will probably be unnoticeable to the average person who is not a seasoned audio professional, but there is a difference. So what interests me is >

Comment: if there's a fundamental difference between the working principle of loudspeakers vs. headphones. I have no experience of modifying headphones.

Comment: @user158589 What I meant by they don't care about polarity is that an audio signal will have no DC offset. Flipping the connection will make the phase flipped but you won't be able to hear it through just one driver. This is very different to connecting a battery, which depending on voltage and driver impedance I wouldn't do because you could burn out the driver. I'm making an assumption that there is no active circuitry in the headphones and the drivers aren't atypical.

Comment: Oh okay fair enough. ((there's a minimum character limit for a comment))